# chmod a+x to all directory and content

Tags: chmod

I am trying to install a library called libtool

i am getting "./configure: line 2668: libltdl/config/mkstamp: Permission denied" when i do ./configure

how can i chmod a+x all the libtool directory to prevent this error ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful before making permissions changes so deep like this. Before you start, make a backup:
`cd libtool`
`find . -printf "chmod %m %p\n" > ~/perms.txt`
Then, to change to make the whole thing a+x (bad idea, but meh):
`find . -exec chmod a+x '{}' \;`

If anything goes wrong, you can always revert afterwards:
`cat ~/perms.txt | bash`

Comment: chmod -R is better and way less complicated

Comment: That's already been mentioned on two other answers. You're right in that it's less complicated and faster, as were @skinp and @ramesh earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Most version of chmod have a recursive flag:

```
chmod -R a+x folder
```

Comment: I have no idea why I forgot about that!

Comment: Is it possible to do that without crossing FileSystem boundaries ? I have a NFS mount somewhere in the folder tree that I don't want to chmod.

Answer (score 0):

chmod -R +x /path/to/folder will work though